# Session Fails to Start

Tags: 8, sessions

In my drupal site, it has been working fine for a while, but recently users have not been able to log in to the site (including me as admin). I am seeing the following error in my php logs:

```
[28-Jul-2018 20:07:02 UTC] Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Failed to start the session" at (webroot)/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php line 145
```

I went to look at the code and i see it corresponds with the following lines:

```
    if (!session_start()) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Failed to start the session');
    }
```

I have tried clearing the sessions tables as well as the cache using core/rebuild.php and nothing seems to be working. Another note for this I had to add this line temporarily

```
$settings['rebuild_access'] = TRUE;
```

in my settings.php to get it to work also, because the token generator script was throwing another error like below:

```
[28-Jul-2018 20:39:01 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Drupal\Core\Site\Settings::initialize(), 1 passed in (webroot)/core/scripts/rebuild_token_calculator.sh on line 22 and exactly 3 expected in (webroot)/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Site/Settings.php:108
```

Not sure if this is related to the main error or not, but thought it may be worth mentioning.

Comment: Check for disk space issues. If you have run out of space, this is one possible symptom.

Comment: Seems like I'm good on disc space, only using 200MB of 100GB available, DB size is only 12MB.

Comment: The other classic reason for session failing to start is there having been some output before the session_start() call. For example if index.php has a newline before the "<?php". Worth checking to see if all the source files are as they should be, in case one has somehow got corrupted.

Comment: oh ok I will try and go through and see if I can find anything. Before this started happening no one has really accessed the webserver so seems unlikely. I have been looking around to see if there is some way to get the reason why session_start() fails in php, is there something i can add to get some kind of trace on the failure? (Also for what its worth, i found that php is saving the session data to the /tmp folder on my server)